# Choose database from folder Code QL on Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, parsing, codeql

I would like to use Code QL in Visual Studio Code to parse a Java project and I am selecting the source folder of my java project after clicking on the icon "choose database from folder". My project's folder looks like this:
[image]

I am receiving the error `'c:\Users\mouna\git\chess\java-chess' does not contain a dataset directory.` , how can I fix this? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you created a Codeql database for your Java project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to install the codeQL package in your machine. Makesure codeql command is accessible from your command line by adding it in environment variable PATH. Then follow the instruction [here](https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-cli/creating-codeql-databases/) and create a database for your codebase

```
ex : codeql database  create projectName-database --language=java
      --command="mvn clean install" --source-root="C:\code\projectFolder"
```

Then upload the newly created database to VS code.
Follow the instructions [here](https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-for-visual-studio-code/analyzing-your-projects/#analyzing-your-projects) to to run your analysis

Comment: I did this exactly, and it still gives me the same error

Comment: `Spawned process exited abnormally (code 1; tried to run: [D:\Tools\codeql-win64\codeql\tools\win64\runner.exe, cmd.exe, /C, type, NUL, &&, D:\Tools\codeql-win64\codeql\xml\tools\index-files.cmd, D:\Projects\IntelliJ Projects\codeql_target_repo\java-database\working\files-to-index1524764287162886810.list])` and this was the command: `codeql database create java-database --language=java --command="mvn clean package"`